# Spring Integration: How to inject header-mapper globally instead of every component

Tags: spring-integration

We have a requirement to trace all the component of Spring Integration. For this, I need to add some data in headers which can be done using any implementation of org.springframework.integration.mapping.HeaderMapper (example: DefaultHttpHeaderMapper, DefaultJmsHeaderMapper, DefaultMailHeaderMapper, JmsHeaderMapper) and then using header-mapper attribute we can inject this.

Is there any way by which we can inject header-mapper globally instead of injecting it in all the components individually.

```
<int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter id="jmsIn" channel="input_channel" destination-name="testqueue" header-mapper="testJMSHeaderMapper"/>
```

But going via above approach, I need to inject header-mapper in every component. Do we have any optimised way by which I can configure this in one place.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `BeanPostProcessor` and add the mapper to all beans of type `ChannelPublishingJmsMessageListener` in `postProcessAfterInitialization`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Gary! I need to add mapper to all the spring integration components in all the routes (for example: int-http:inbound-gateway, int-http:outbound-gateway,all channel adapter, etc). My example above seems to be confusing limited to jms but ideally I am looking out for all components. Could you please suggest for this.

Comment: You can use the same technique for all components. Just look at the XML schema to determine the class name.

Comment: I have tried the above approach.
First of all find all the java class name for all components. I have referred the xsd for http to check the http inbound and outbound gateway but unable to find them. Not sure if I am referring to correct xsd (http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http/spring-integration-http.xsd). I have only the mapping of the below:
int-http:inbound-gateway - org.springframework.integration.http.inbound.HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway
int-http:outbound-gateway - org.springframework.integration.http.outbound.AbstractHttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler

Comment: Can you please guide me on to find the component name for others - int-http:inbound-gateway, int-http:inbound-channel-adapter, int:transformer, int:header-enricher, int:chain, int:router, etc.

Secondly, in the below example how can I retrieve existing headerMapper so as to verify if the header value that I need to insert is already existing or not. I will add the header value if doesnt exist.

Comment: @Override
  public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
    if (beanName.contains("org.springframework.integration.http.inbound.HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway")) {
      HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway inGateway = (HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway) bean;
      HeaderMapper<HttpHeaders> headerMapper = // <need to get the existing HeaderMapper>;

Comment: Apologies for sending the message in parts. Also I couldnt send the complete code snapshot due to character limitation in comments.

Comment: That schema is old - did you read the comment at the top? Use the [schemas on GitHub](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-http/src/main/resources/org/springframework/integration/http/config/spring-integration-http-5.1.xsd#L416). Don't put code in comments; it's unreadable - edit the question instead. You shouldn't be looking at bean names, use the class names instead. No there is no getter for the existing mapper - why do you care if you want to unconditionally replace it? Routers, chains etc don't have header mappers.